# How to know which is the generated Url with Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

I'm working with retrofit and I want to know which is the generated url.

I've tried with setRequestInterceptor and setProfiler.

The last one gives me the url but not query params... so It's not the complete one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who want to know

```
 RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.BASIC)
            .setEndpoint(Metadata.CURRENT_SERVER)
            .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
service.yourRequest(params...).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        Log.d(TAG, call.request().url().toString()); // here
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

`call.request().url(),` where `call` is an instance of `retrofit2.Call`